# ActionMailer workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am newbie in Rails, therefore sorry for silly question. For sending emails I use ActionMailer with Rails 2.3.5. The syntax is following

> > deliver_maintest1
> >
> > deliver_maintest2

in model of instance of ActionMailer I have

> > def maintest1
> >
> > end
> >
> > def maintest2
> >
> > end

Inside definitions I set recipient, subject, headers,...As I understand there is no any explicity defined method **mail** which is actually sent email. Emails are sent from def maintest1 and maintest2. The problem is before sending email I need to define few counters how many emails were sent thought maintest1 and maintest2. Now take into account I have tens defs like maintest. So I need a common place for all those defs. In your opinion what's the best solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On rails 3 and above you could use an `observer`. These get called after every mail delivery, passing through the message object. You just need to implement a `delivered_email` class method and register it.

```
class EmailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    # do something with message
  end
end
```

Then, hook it into mail with

```
Mail.register_observer(EmailObserver)
```

This doesn't work on rails 2.x, which doesn't use the mail gem (it uses tmail from the ruby standard library.)

On 2.3.x I would try something like

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def deliver!(mail=@mail)
    super
    # do your logging here
  end
end
```

Comment: D'oh, just realised you are on rails 2.3 - the above only applies to rails >= 3.  On rails 2, you might try overriding the deliver method on your mailer

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure there is def deliver in ActionMailer. Do you know how can I define after_filter for ActionMailer?

Comment: Like Frederick said, "def deliver" would have worked for rails 3+

Answer (score 1):

You would be calling "Mailer.deliver_maintest" to send the mails out to anyone, to count the nos of times you sent a particular email you just need to keep track of it each time you call "Mailer.deliver_maintest" .

You can store that counter either the database or somewhere. something like this.

```
  // Some lines of code to Update the counter for the mailer
  Mailer.deliver_maintest
```

You can also use a third party email tool like PostMark to send your email ( with them you can associate each email with tags, and I just generally use those tags to keep track of emails sent out ).

Comment: thanks a lot, but I have tens of them (maintest1, maintest...). I don't want to change counter outside of maintest. I thought there should be something more convenient. I'll take a look at PostMark